# How to change in Jenkins Pipelinegitlab status in cases tests failing or succeed?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

How can I change the GitLab status in Jenkins-Pipeline?
I know I can do something like this:

```groovy
stage('Tests') {
   steps {
      updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'test', state: 'pending'
 (...Doing other stages and steps)

post {

    }
    success {
        updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'test', state: 'success'
    }
    failure {
        updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'test', state: 'failed'
    }
}
```

But this is only done when the whole pipeline is finished - My Question: how can I change the status of the gitlab status (test) immediately the stage test is finished (cases: success and failure dependend of the status of the test-step)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `post` directive can be used inside of a `stage` as well (see [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post)):

```groovy
stage('Tests') {
  steps {
    updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'test', state: 'pending'
    // ...
  }
  post {
    success {
      updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'test', state: 'success'
    }
    failure {
      updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'test', state: 'failed'
    }
  }
}
```